# BPMN 2.0: How do i model an ongoing process?

Tags: process, bpmn, business-process-management

How can i model a process in bpmn 2.0, which is ongoing?
E.g. i have to model a process with 5 steps. Lets assume A, B, C, D, E.
The complication is that there is no clear end as after step E, step A would start again. So the flow is like A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> A --> B and so on...

Any suggestions how i can do that?

I did try to model: start --> A,b,c,d,e --> end. But this does not display that after E starts A again. Maybe some triggers can help?